# Tabbing not possible on buttons after applying jquery uniform

Tags: jquery, button, uniform

I am using [jQuery uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) on my forms. I found that after applying uniform, when tabbing buttons(and radio buttons) are skipped. Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: I am assuming this is uniform http://uniformjs.com/

Comment: Tabbing works fine on their example page.  Could you post your HTML?

Comment: @John: what browser are you using? In Chrome 10 on Windows 7, I'm not able to tab between fields at all.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 - my head isn't in the right place this morning... Tabbing may not be possible on all browsers since most browsers only allow tabbing on form elements.  The radio/checkbox buttons aren't form elements, they are images made to look like form elements.

Comment: @John Yes tabbing works on their example page, but there are no buttons. And I'm using Windows 7 with Firefox 4/ IE 8/ Chrome 10

Comment: I have found the reason but, can't find a solution to it. So it happens that uniform adds a div and span around the button, and makes the button transparent(opacity:0). So even if tabbing would work, you wouldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is semi-resolved in the current version. There's a very slight shadow around items you've tabbed onto, *as long as* you don't select a radio button with your mouse (in other words, you have to tab/arrow to move around and space to select).

Presumably you could update the sprite.png to make the shadow a good deal more obvious, if needed.